# REST API URL/Endpoints design

Tags: rest

I have a debate here about some REST API design, the case is:
we have courses table and lectures table, course has many lectures, "lectures are instances from a course", however the debate is how we can get the lectures?
/course/id/lectures 
OR
/lectures/course_id
OR we should let the 2 options available?

Thank you.

Comment: Would the response to a query for a course not contain links to the related lectures? That is how I understand REST. The response to a query gives you information (links) to what you can do with it. Here, e.g. query for the lectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first intuition would be that you have to ask for the lectures of a course with something like

> GET /root/courses/course1/lectures

which would yield a list of links to the lectures assigned to that course.
Then, you could query the details about those lectures with:

> GET /root/lectures/lecture1

using the links looking like: `/root/lectures/lecture1` etc. obtained from the first query.